# R extract text with regex and save to vectors. For loop across multiple directories

Tags: r, regex, for-loop

I have a list of files (result.file.names)

```
str(files)
chr [1:100] "bootstrap1/results_outfile1.txt" "bootstrap1/results_outfile2.txt" "bootstrap1/results_outfile3.txt" ...
```

files contain this type of text:

```
    {u'likelihood': -40563.03277, u'ml_tree': u'(cretaceaPI631721:0.01986343369712553764,((marinaPI516711:0.00342486721337833871,marinaPI419391:0.00439557045406125009):0.02057525413645854007,(prostrataPI577445:0.01814072969763430923,((rhodopeaW619154:0.01102506287325524803,rhodopeaSA43026:0.00988925069197059761):0.00474817094454488275,sativaglomerataPI577567:0.01961388465250675159):0.00161938724432756135):0.00384093064837489435):0.00445211181667617192,truncatulaW64996:0.03326867403662570749):0.0;', u'partitions': {u'1': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.669133, 3.027675, 0.703665, 0.839487, 3.419337, 1.0], u'name': u'gene6', u'frequencies': [0.292, 0.157, 0.175, 0.376]}, u'0': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [1.339908, 4.287687, 0.779025, 0.969835, 3.515225, 1.0], u'name': u'gene2', u'frequencies': [0.303, 0.164, 0.196, 0.337]}, u'3': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.546239, 2.327466, 0.694809, 0.626631, 2.03728, 1.0], u'name': u'gene20B', u'frequencies': [0.294, 0.165, 0.186, 0.356]}, u'2': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.791557, 4.292835, 0.810393, 1.104181, 2.854274, 1.0], u'name': u'gene20A', u'frequencies': [0.299, 0.171, 0.173, 0.356]}, u'5': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.801513, 2.664222, 0.685992, 1.465601, 3.70961, 1.0], u'name': u'gene35', u'frequencies': [0.294, 0.155, 0.189, 0.362]}, u'4': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.666665, 3.932293, 1.012807, 0.631296, 2.635027, 1.0], u'name': u'gene28', u'frequencies': [0.298, 0.173, 0.181, 0.348]}, u'7': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.834878, 3.467245, 0.990482, 1.038981, 4.405174, 1.0], u'name': u'gene44', u'frequencies': [0.284, 0.152, 0.183, 0.381]}, u'6': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.79724, 3.092797, 0.663377, 0.987096, 2.309744, 1.0], u'name': u'gene41', u'frequencies': [0.296, 0.166, 0.178, 0.361]}, u'9': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.988022, 2.859719, 0.731658, 0.978527, 3.139754, 1.0], u'name': u'gene60', u'frequencies': [0.285, 0.16, 0.182, 0.374]}, u'8': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.940118, 1.667166, 0.581149, 0.308618, 1.912549, 1.0], u'name': u'gene49', u'frequencies': [0.291, 0.163, 0.182, 0.365]}}}
{u'likelihood': -4216.778335, u'ml_tree': u'((cretaceaPI631721:0.02585480855056009053,(marinaPI516711:0.00302287739988804476,marinaPI419391:0.00492764788913652510):0.01886326220937559889):0.00569811409029884631,(sativaglomerataPI577567:0.02386936810593148425,((rhodopeaW619154:0.01021163111000199936,rhodopeaSA43026:0.00951101466387962655):0.01010166362035459613,prostrataPI577445:0.02085983976718608704):0.00193049473998346973):0.00244017359086532359,truncatulaW64996:0.03071445596771318898):0.0;', u'partitions': {u'0': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [1.028417, 4.306698, 1.161761, 1.016902, 3.754074, 1.0], u'name': u'gene54', u'frequencies': [0.287, 0.168, 0.193, 0.352]}}}
```

I would like to extract text (the number after `{u'likelihood':`) from them and save each hit from each file in a different vector.
I tried this with a for loop

```
wd <- getwd()
dirs <- dir(wd, pattern="bootstrap[[:alnum:]]*$")

for (d in dirs){
  files <- file.path(d, paste0("results_outfile",1:11, ".txt"))
  for (f in files){
    lines <- readLines(f)
    likelihoods <- regmatches(lines, gregexpr("'likelihood':\\s*\\K[^,]+", text, perl=TRUE))
    results <- paste("results",f,sep="")
    assign(results, likelihoods)
}
}
```

but I get a error

> Error in as.character(text) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to
>   vector of type 'character'

I am not also entirely sure that my for loop is correct

Comment: You may read the file in, and then run `regmatches(text, gregexpr("'likelihood':\\s*\\K[^,]+", text, perl=TRUE))`

Comment: Note your regex should be PCRE flavor: `read.pattern(result.file.names, pattern = "(?<='likelihood': ).*?(?=,)", perl=TRUE)`, or the pattern can be as above.

Comment: I used the first method but gives a new error(see edit above)

Comment: Now solved, I replaced "text" with "lines" in likelihooods <- . My bad

Comment: Yeah, it should be `likelihoods <- regmatches(lines, gregexpr("'likelihood':\\s*\\K[^,]+", lines, perl=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following PCRE regex based approach to extract the values between `'likelihood':` and a comma:

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection("{u'likelihood': -40563.03277, u'ml_tree': u'(cretaceaPI631721:0.01986343369712553764,((marinaPI516711:0.00342486721337833871,marinaPI419391:0.00439557045406125009):0.02057525413645854007,(prostrataPI577445:0.01814072969763430923,((rhodopeaW619154:0.01102506287325524803,rhodopeaSA43026:0.00988925069197059761):0.00474817094454488275,sativaglomerataPI577567:0.01961388465250675159):0.00161938724432756135):0.00384093064837489435):0.00445211181667617192,truncatulaW64996:0.03326867403662570749):0.0;', u'partitions': {u'1': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.669133, 3.027675, 0.703665, 0.839487, 3.419337, 1.0], u'name': u'gene6', u'frequencies': [0.292, 0.157, 0.175, 0.376]}, u'0': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [1.339908, 4.287687, 0.779025, 0.969835, 3.515225, 1.0], u'name': u'gene2', u'frequencies': [0.303, 0.164, 0.196, 0.337]}, u'3': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.546239, 2.327466, 0.694809, 0.626631, 2.03728, 1.0], u'name': u'gene20B', u'frequencies': [0.294, 0.165, 0.186, 0.356]}, u'2': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.791557, 4.292835, 0.810393, 1.104181, 2.854274, 1.0], u'name': u'gene20A', u'frequencies': [0.299, 0.171, 0.173, 0.356]}, u'5': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.801513, 2.664222, 0.685992, 1.465601, 3.70961, 1.0], u'name': u'gene35', u'frequencies': [0.294, 0.155, 0.189, 0.362]}, u'4': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.666665, 3.932293, 1.012807, 0.631296, 2.635027, 1.0], u'name': u'gene28', u'frequencies': [0.298, 0.173, 0.181, 0.348]}, u'7': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.834878, 3.467245, 0.990482, 1.038981, 4.405174, 1.0], u'name': u'gene44', u'frequencies': [0.284, 0.152, 0.183, 0.381]}, u'6': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.79724, 3.092797, 0.663377, 0.987096, 2.309744, 1.0], u'name': u'gene41', u'frequencies': [0.296, 0.166, 0.178, 0.361]}, u'9': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.988022, 2.859719, 0.731658, 0.978527, 3.139754, 1.0], u'name': u'gene60', u'frequencies': [0.285, 0.16, 0.182, 0.374]}, u'8': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [0.940118, 1.667166, 0.581149, 0.308618, 1.912549, 1.0], u'name': u'gene49', u'frequencies': [0.291, 0.163, 0.182, 0.365]}}}
{u'likelihood': -4216.778335, u'ml_tree': u'((cretaceaPI631721:0.02585480855056009053,(marinaPI516711:0.00302287739988804476,marinaPI419391:0.00492764788913652510):0.01886326220937559889):0.00569811409029884631,(sativaglomerataPI577567:0.02386936810593148425,((rhodopeaW619154:0.01021163111000199936,rhodopeaSA43026:0.00951101466387962655):0.01010166362035459613,prostrataPI577445:0.02085983976718608704):0.00193049473998346973):0.00244017359086532359,truncatulaW64996:0.03071445596771318898):0.0;', u'partitions': {u'0': {u'alpha': 0.02, u'rates': [1.028417, 4.306698, 1.161761, 1.016902, 3.754074, 1.0], u'name': u'gene54', u'frequencies': [0.287, 0.168, 0.193, 0.352]}}}"))
likelihoods <- regmatches(lines, gregexpr("'likelihood':\\s*\\K[^,]+", lines, perl=TRUE))
likelihoods
## => [[1]]
##    [1] "-40563.03277"
##   
##    [[2]]
##    [1] "-4216.778335"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/dO9QKH)

**Pattern details**:

- `'likelihood':` - match  a literal substring `'likelihood':`
- `\\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `\\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `[^,]+` - (this is what you will get in return) 1 or more chars other than `,`